# CAML to Return rows Where Created is Between 2 dates

Tags: caml-query, caml, date-time

The below query returns the entirety of the List, instead of those which fall inside the correct date range.

I have tried querying with and without a time added to the date.

> ```
>             CamlQuery CamlQuery = new CamlQuery();
>             var qs = "<Query>" +
>                     "  <Where>" +
>                     "    <And>" +
>                     "      <Geq>" +
>                     "        <FieldRef Name='Created' />" +
>                     "          <Value IncludeTimeValue='True' Type='DateTime'>2017-08-30T00:00:00Z</Value>" +
>                     "      </Geq>" +
>                     "      <Leq>" +
>                     "        <FieldRef Name='Created' />" +
>                     "        <Value IncludeTimeValue='True' Type='DateTime'>2017-08-31T23:59:00Z</Value>" +
>                     "      </Leq>" +
>                     "    </And>" +
>                     "  </Where>" +
>                     "</Query>";
>
>             CamlQuery.ViewXml = qs;
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `View` tag around your whole CAML string:

> ```
>             CamlQuery CamlQuery = new CamlQuery();
>             var qs = "<View><Query>" +
>                     "  <Where>" +
>                     "    <And>" +
>                     "      <Geq>" +
>                     "        <FieldRef Name='Created' />" +
>                     "          <Value IncludeTimeValue='True' Type='DateTime'>2017-08-30T00:00:00Z</Value>" +
>                     "      </Geq>" +
>                     "      <Leq>" +
>                     "        <FieldRef Name='Created' />" +
>                     "        <Value IncludeTimeValue='True' Type='DateTime'>2017-08-31T23:59:00Z</Value>" +
>                     "      </Leq>" +
>                     "    </And>" +
>                     "  </Where>" +
>                     "</Query></View>";
>
>             CamlQuery.ViewXml = qs;
> ```

Comment: Wow. that was it!

Comment: On a somewhat related note, is it possible to use Linq instead of CAML? I`ve looked but what ive seen asks for SPMetal on the server which i wont have access to.

Comment: Linq to SharePoint requires SPMetal. SPMetal can be found on any SharePoint installation, in the hive\bin folder. However, this also requires the code using Linq to SharePoint to run on the server itself, with the server-side object model. It cannot be used with the CSOM.